# Proxy Broker Error Use async with instead

Tags: python, selenium, github, command-line, proxy

I have downloaded an installed proxy broker as well as aiodns, maxminddb and aiohttp.  I keep getting the error message below.  Any idea why?  I am using Anaconda Python 3 on windows.  I've look at other forums who have experienced same issues but they were unable to solve it.  Any ideas?  Thank you.  I am wanting a good proxy checker as it so many proxies fail or do not work.

[image]

I entered `proxybroker find --types HTTP HTTPS --lvl High --countries US --strict -l 10`

http://proxybroker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I have tried a reinstall to address this but there does not seem to be any fixes and there seem to be open tickets with this issue.  Any ideas on how to fix or move on to different proxy project?

```
  C:\Windows\system32>proxybroker find --types HTTP HTTPS --lvl High --countries US --strict -l 10
    C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py:576: DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead
      warnings.warn("Use async with instead", DeprecationWarning)
    C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py:139: DeprecationWarning: ClientSession.close() is a coroutine
      warnings.warn(self._msg, DeprecationWarning)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seems to not have updated for last 1 year and their `requirements.txt` is below

```
aiohttp
aiodns
maxminddb
```

Which is not binding to any version. This is wrong as new package changes can change how your program works.

Anyways the fix is to go on a older version of aiohttp. Old enough to `2.0.0`. So after installing this package run

```
pip install aiohttp==2.0.0

$ proxybroker find --types HTTP HTTPS --lvl High --countries US --strict -l 10
/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/so2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:565: DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead
  warnings.warn("Use async with instead", DeprecationWarning)
<Proxy US 0.43s [HTTP: High] 159.203.112.118:3128>
```

A warning but the program still starts running well

Comment: Thanks heaps.  It still gives a deprecation warning though.  proxybroker grab --countries Australia --limit 10 --outfile ./proxies.txt  tends not to work for Australia.  It did work though for US proxies which is awesome though I think some commands might still not work because of deprecation warning always present: https://ibb.co/g0nsTa

Comment: Try `--countries AU` instead

Comment: Same issue unfortunately.  No text file is made when using Australia or AU

Comment: The script has little count of proxy list sites. To example, it can to find proxy of US, but can't to find of UK.

Comment: Probably issue related to source urls that they scan

Comment: @TarunLalwani Probably.  I can't really find any other good proxies  checkers and this seems to do the job. I suppose I could design up a job that does something similar but hopefully not necessary.  Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need uninstall original version ProxyBroker, and reinstall from the patched fork https://github.com/Lookyan/ProxyBroker.
It works with last version aiohttp (verified 2.2.3).

The original version now is not supported by its author, and required [patch](https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker/pull/28).

Comment: I tried that.  Unfortunately that did not work.  aiohttp==2.0.0 worked for me it's a shame they don't have Australian proxies though.